# global extrema for 2 variable multi var calc

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find all global extrema of f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 on the region s = {(x,y) : x^2 + y^2 <= 1}
I did this would this be a global minimum at (0,0)
what do you have to do when it says on the region.

Answer (score 1):

True, $(0,0)$ is a global minimum. But also all of the outer rim of the disk is a global maximum.

Comment: how do you do the outer rim?

Comment: How you prove it? Well it is not via the derivative, as you are on the border of the disk $s$. You can prove it by seeing the value of $f$ on that rim $\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2=1\}$ is 1, while at any other point it is less.

Comment: ok then what is the difference between that problem and this one Find all local extrema of f(x,y)=x^2 + y^2. That is, find their locations and values.

Comment: In this case, all local extrema of $f$ are global extrema on the disk $s$. However, a point $(x,y)$ is a local extremum of $f$ iff there exists an environment $E$, s.t. $(x,y) \in E \subseteq s$ so that on $E$, $(x,y)$ is a global extremum of $f$.

Comment: ok I see. although both of the answers would have local minimum at (0, 0)?

Comment: correct, any global extreme is a local extreme, so in both your original question and in the modified question with the open disk, $(0,0)$ is a global and local minimum.